# Routing to a NAT instance across VPCs through a Transit Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have an instance in a private subnet in VPC B. I want to direct all of its outbound traffic through a NAT instance that is in VPC A.
VPC A and B are associated with a Transit Gateway and the instances from each VPC can ping each other. The NAT instance is obviously in a public subnet, and I confirmed it works by routing an instance in a private subnet in the same VPC to the NAT Instance's ENI.
I tried adding the respective routes and its not working, the instance in private subnet in VPC B cannot reach internet. There is definitely some fundamental step I am missing, either in the routing or simply the whole concept.

Would really appreciate the assistance or general direction I should check.

[High level diagram of env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7xxC.png)

Comment: What is the route table for the public subnet? Do you have a `0.0.0.0/0` in it?

Comment: Yeah, public subnet has 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW. The NAT instance needs access to internet and needs to be accessed from public as well. Issue is how do I direct the traffic to the instance first and not the IGW.

Comment: Did you try setting the destination `0.0.0.0/0` in the route table for the private subnet in VPC B to the IP address of the NAT instance? Not sure if that makes sense, but I can't think of anything else. :)

Comment: I sorted it out, it wasnt an issue with routing. I simply didn't set up my NAT instance properly. Once I fixed that it worked.
I actually went with a more complex method and created a Customer Gateway and Site-to-Site VPN connection with the NAT Instance and attached that to my TGW.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out, it wasn't an issue with routing. I simply didn't set up my NAT instance properly. Once I fixed that it worked (Made sure I had proper NAT rules).
I actually went with a more complex method and created a Customer Gateway and Site-to-Site VPN connection with the NAT Instance and attached that to my TGW.